# How to loop through users with passport.js and print userlist onto DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm utilizing the MEAN stack in a task-tracker app that has user accounts. There are regular users (with view-only pages available to them), and then there are admins who can add users and add/remove tasks.

`req.user` will display the current user's request, and in my html view `<%= user.local.property-name %>` will print out the current user's various properties.

Is it possible to loop through the collection of users from passport.js to display for admins? For standard collections, I understand how to do this with standard collections but am not sure with passport.js due to my general unfamiliarity with node, express and mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this by directly querying your data store. Passport doesn't handle this and deals with just getting 1 user signed in or out of your app. If you are storing your users in mongodb on the MEAN stack, you need to directly query the "users" collection. Passport does not need to be involved directly.